# Automatically like a page in Facebook based on user long live token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

As the title reads...

is this possibly?

Workflow should be like:

1.- User is registered, he receives a barcode with a numeric ID.

2.- Time later the user scans barcode in embedded device, it posts the numeric ID to some php magic... and he automatically is noted as "liking" (user likes x) a certain page, no login, no nothing, we should get the user data just based on our first registration. The (embedded device/computer/thing that reads barcodes) must be headless.

Is this even possibly with the current Facebook oAuth model??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you read their terms of service and conditions for this.  If I recall anything other thank clicking a 'like' button would be a breach of their terms.

Comment: http://www.canneszions.com/coca-cola-like-machine-publicis-edologic/ i don't think this would be possibly if you were right...

Comment: I'm pretty sure users would have known what they were getting into and would have had to of tied their facebook account to their RFID previously.  Since it is a high profile company, I'm pretty sure they closely worked with Facebook on that one.  Right from developer docs: "If a user grants you a publishing permission, you must still obtain consent from the user before taking any action on the user's behalf, such as publishing content or creating an event."

Comment: i believe.. the action... of the user.. will be placing the bracelete on the like box.... making it intentionally.... no harm done to the terms of service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed as the terms of service now.